# How to give Apache access to ip-tables on ubuntu

Tags: iptables, ubuntu-14.04, sudo, apache2

I've run the below script on a fresh `Ubuntu 14.04.5 x64` box. It works to the point where apache blocks my IP address for too many requests as expected. However, my IP address isn't added to `iptables`. I just get a standard 403 but I would like packets to be dropped with no error.

I think the problem is a permissions one where `apache` isn't able to run `ip-tables`. But I can't figure it out as I have given the `apache` user `www-data` the ability to run `iptables` in the `sudoers` file.

Any help appreciated, I've been faffing about with this all day!

```
#!/bin/sh

apt-get update
apt-get -y install apache2

# Install mod evasive
apt-get -y install libapache2-mod-evasive

# Enable it
a2enmod evasive
a2enconf evasive

# Create log directory
mkdir /var/log/mod_evasive
chown -R www-data:www-data /var/log/mod_evasive

# Config for mod evasive
cat <<'EOF' > /etc/apache2/mods-available/evasive.conf
  <IfModule mod_evasive20.c>
      DOSHashTableSize     3097

      # Allow 5 requests for the same resource request per second. Per-IP
      DOSPageCount          5
      DOSPageInterval       1

      # Allow up to 50 requests across the domain per second. Per-IP
      DOSSiteCount          50
      DOSSiteInterval       1

      # Block user by IP for 60 minutes
      DOSBlockingPeriod     60

      DOSSystemCommand      "sudo /usr/local/bin/ban_ip.sh %s"

      DOSLogDir             /var/log/mod_evasive
      DOSWhitelist          188.88.90.71
      DOSWhitelist          188.88.90.72
      DOSWhitelist          188.88.90.73
  </IfModule>
EOF

# Config for banning users
cat <<'EOF' > /usr/local/bin/ban_ip.sh
#!/bin/sh

# Offending IP as detected by mod_evasive
IP=$1

# Path to iptables binary executed by user www-data through sudo
IPTABLES="/sbin/iptables"

# mod_evasive lock directory
MOD_EVASIVE_LOGDIR=/var/log/mod_evasive

# Add the following firewall rule (block IP)
sudo $IPTABLES -I INPUT -s $IP -j DROP

# Unblock offending IP after 2 hours through the 'at' command; see 'man at' for further details
echo "sudo $IPTABLES -D INPUT -s $IP -j DROP" | sudo at now + 1 minute

# Remove lock file for future checks
sudo rm -f "$MOD_EVASIVE_LOGDIR"/dos-"$IP"
EOF

echo 'www-data ALL=NOPASSWD: /sbin/iptables *, /usr/bin/at *' | EDITOR='tee -a' visudo
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never used mod-evasive, but after skimming your script, it looks like you forgot to make your `/usr/local/bin/ban_ip.sh` executable - if I understand your setup correctly.

Additionally I don't see any reason for an extra sudo in your iptables command, because in evasive.conf the entire `usr/local/bin/ban_ip.sh` script is configured to be started by sudo. If it runs, it runs with root privilege.

You might add some statement like:

```
echo here we are at 1 >>/tmp/evasive.testlog
```

shortly after #!/bin/sh just to see wether your script gets executed at all.

Comment: Such a simply thing to over look. You're right, that was it! Thanks!